# Testing DNS truncated queries over TCP with dig

Tags: dns, tcp, dig

I want to test if my network supports EDNS0. It means that if the record is bigger than 512byte, the DNS will be over TCP. It will ne truncated at firts using UDP ,the it willbe over tcp.

I'm using the dig tool.

Can someone give me an address to test with ,that contains records more than 512 bytes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ dig +dnssec any .
```

If you get a response, that'll confirm.  You'll see TC set if no EDNS0.  Or not if it used UDP via large packet size negotiated with EDNS0.  Here's the latter:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-4.3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> +dnssec any .
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3126
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 21, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.                              IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
.                       86400   IN      RRSIG   SOA 8 0 86400 20141227170000 20141220160000 22603 . BflaxGqdW1hFum4ex62bGRA9oR2UmciaOwmrPudH+7bDqoZU1nCsdUJe tUvw67XgwEvTImWyr0YRW59Rt1WRa2WIx2JgzipTz0E9Z/gAfNimilIq lo0VQvtqI8XnzX0aluI/D5h/mCdLYoa4kUU/JYbAyGbuYlVcxTUEND9C cZE=
.                       86400   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2014122001 1800 900 604800 86400
.                       86400   IN      RRSIG   NSEC 8 0 86400 20141227170000 20141220160000 22603 . nEPYsfblNfADiwm0DDv0UdXxM2DzUvr5sd6DXNSJsLmOtBFfE+ZRj2Ic 5ijwKgAVq2oOOWMzh2iL6t5vIrJSdCzj+KzwpUQoXiRxw6WmLDgNi4hP RxLkdQuXeGorMiBcmMGZ0KLu+GS+X5FgbpFraysmTKwxF5QzhvPuDfFw DPk=
.                       86400   IN      NSEC    abogado. NS SOA RRSIG NSEC DNSKEY
.                       172800  IN      RRSIG   DNSKEY 8 0 172800 20141225000000 20141210000000 19036 . EkXcXw65ncw09tkhq1JwJLv0CX6vlzieJg+80zm894XYLa6rBztHaem4 n2ur2kzOi1yPpCt79mIHbJii8HinMrPTln8wsDVxKy41GHsx2G1+2KaU C/IuFsI+D/lQ8A07R7ozXYKmbERSg0KTqtBBIetE9ZLptQVkkdmuJ15E OiEE7unOU4aD3wIKjsymTzSSwS9Qb5sKCTvSF9ct/a3XuOy6Mr/T3x5Y EUCY2U4QmnP8Oao8ukJQop8tVfbMKc02LTZ0ZeKjt0BguAYeeehzAiez dCcKEMDLU8G2wCxvvC7YQrwaS/MlKl6A0VsCXhcxSum1tD4E4LVOp18z eaTxdw==
.                       172800  IN      DNSKEY  257 3 8 AwEAAagAIKlVZrpC6Ia7gEzahOR+9W29euxhJhVVLOyQbSEW0O8gcCjF FVQUTf6v58fLjwBd0YI0EzrAcQqBGCzh/RStIoO8g0NfnfL2MTJRkxoX bfDaUeVPQuYEhg37NZWAJQ9VnMVDxP/VHL496M/QZxkjf5/Efucp2gaD X6RS6CXpoY68LsvPVjR0ZSwzz1apAzvN9dlzEheX7ICJBBtuA6G3LQpz W5hOA2hzCTMjJPJ8LbqF6dsV6DoBQzgul0sGIcGOYl7OyQdXfZ57relS Qageu+ipAdTTJ25AsRTAoub8ONGcLmqrAmRLKBP1dfwhYB4N7knNnulq QxA+Uk1ihz0=
.                       172800  IN      DNSKEY  256 3 8 AwEAAaPD7Y7XIi1MOEREJNTrRhyqsY3gff6JWzg+XCbqut1sbcbvqyss Hw8DT1AkRaAC92pO8xuyq5QEgEPL1IHfABLwpwXI5gTj4gdwi86bpkml Ws9fRpnn4DPDCTdrnxIejJXgClHikLJF3u3CdpNCMijq4CKdQbMlRZ3a vv+G7rh7
.                       518400  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20141227170000 20141220160000 22603 . OFzDcFqDXEuMP33XyF89i2Hf7OhH7Pd9xshFtKrgGvJGj0j65/e+m0ER 6GWRUL3RFnwEdmDaq+DaPTjlaKxvUo+VlfwB9TSwMDUq8m0Q6iopcLpv j0QG2HdN+EXZM21B5cg9+rLh9rtLLf6wcheQ7d4s8VIhIusTgbMAm+LN jN8=
.                       518400  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.

;; Query time: 1002 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Dec 20 19:37:11 MST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 1507
```